# JavaScript prototype inheritance and constructors

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Considering the fallowing example :

```
function A(obj) {
}

B.prototype = new A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;

function B(obj) {
    A.call(this, obj);
}
```

where B should inherit the prototype from A. Is this code correct? Why is it that the function A is called once when the script is parsed, without any instance from A or B being declared? Is it because of the fallowing line?

```
B.prototype = new A;
```

If so, how can B inherit A without calling function A in the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid calling A again if you use Object.create

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
```

Object.create creates a new object that has the given parameter as its prototype (the actual prototype, not the "prototype" property). It is not present in old browsers (IE < 8, FF < 4) but you can (for our purposes) create your own version if you want to. The basic idea is precisely creating a version of `A` that does nothing (and therefore can be called wihthout undesired side effects)

```
if(!Object.create){
    Object.create = function(proto){
        var F = function(){};
        F.prototype = proto;
        return new F(); //BTW, always use parenthesis when calling new. It looks better.
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do is never put logic inside the constructor function and instead put it in a separate `init` method that must be called afterwards.